# check the value of a word inside a string

Tags: java, string, token

I have a string like

```
String example =  "Tag: something Id: somethingElse Score: 0.8";
```

How can i check if `Score` is higher/equal/lower than 0.

Answer (score 2):

By using `lastIndexOf` and `substring` from `String` object, you can get the value from the string.

```
String scoreStr = example.substring(example.lastIndexOf("Score:") + "Score:".length());
double score = Double.parseDouble(scoreStr.trim());
```

Now, you can do an `if`...`else if` statement on `score`.

PS: If you want it returned as float, change the last line like so:

```
float score = Float.parseFloat(scoreStr.trim());
```

Comment: this will not work. First you forgot to add length of `"Score:"` in calculating index to get scoreStr. Second: you should first trim your `scoreStr` before converting it to double. Third: there is no method as `parseDouble` in `String`. I think it should be `Double.parseDouble(str);`

Comment: it is not the last three chars always.. it may be something like 0.8 (as the example) or like 0.2345356 or 1.344 or....

Comment: not really, it's still not working, String doesn't have a parseDouble() method

Comment: @user992821, I'm not reading the last 3 characters. Read & understand my code please.

Comment: @Stivlo, thanks...lol. Funny enough, I am looking at `Double.parseDouble()`. I guess I was typing too fast.

Answer (score 2):

just as an alternative to @The-Elite-Gentleman:

```
String [] tokens = example.split(" |:");
Double score = Double.valueOf( tokens[tokens.length - 1] )
```

In case the score is always last, of course :)

Answer (score 1):

```
String score = example.substring("the index of 0", "the index of 8"); //Without quotes//

double scoreDouble = Double.parseDouble(aString);
```

Then check the scoreDouble.

Answer (score 1):

If the format is stable, you could look for "Score: ", get the remainder of the string and parse as a float or double number, according to the precision you need.

```
String example = "Tag: something Id: somethingElse Score: 0.8";
String search = "Score: ";
int scorePosition = example.indexOf(search) + search.length();
float num = Float.parseFloat(example.substring(scorePosition));
```

After that it would be a simple if on `num`. You should also catch NumberFormatException, especially in case the string format could be wrong at times.